# Was the widespread use of PRS in the 90s because 90s Gibson guitars were low quality?

Tags: electric-guitar

Was the 90s widespread adoption of PRS guitars really to do with the low quality Gibson guitars of the era?

I have heard that the 90s were not Gibson's best decade and was wondering if that led to more PRS adoption?

It could be that PRS simply had a sound that was popular during the 90s but I was under the impression that competitors dropping the ball also had something to do with it.

Comment: Not sure if we can definitively answer this. I have a 95 Les Paul Studio that is great. We know the types of metal that became big in the 90s were often played with PRS + Dual Recto. Also PRS was only founded in 85, so for them to take off in the 90s could just be that’s when people first started to hear about them. And the 90s was a decade of guitar - everyone sold a lot of guitars. I think it’s a lot more complicated than what Gibson was doing or not doing.

Comment: As far as I know PRS guitars were quite a bit more expansive that the typical Gibson models. So they do not really compete. I’d think that especially professional musicians would rather go for the more expensive guitar because they need an instrument that plays really well.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Agreed, but I don't know that it has to be *definitively* answered, just "documentedly." It would be a fascinating bit of organological history either way, and surely there's some bit of support other than "Well seems to me that ___ makes sense"... Also Neil, any chance you could start the train rolling towards documentation by nailing down where "you heard" the idea?

Comment: Lazy has a good point. When I bought my Gibson USA LP studio for $700 in 95, the most affordable PRS model was the CE Bolt-On at over $1000.

Comment: A guitar is a tool, but it is also wardrobe, and playing new designs and builders distinguishes you from older artists and styles. Could be quality, but "we're something new and look it" is an important factor.

Comment: I just saw a video from Five Watt World with David Grissom, who is a great roots-rock sideman and session player, and he goes in a lot about how he developed the DGT with PRS. I'm guessing that artist relations work had a lot to do with the PRS rise, no matter the quality of Gibsons.

Comment: I think the most likely answers to this question are “no” and “we can’t ever be certain”. Too many changes happened related to PRS and the guitar market in general in the 90s for it to be mainly about one thing. PRS didn’t even have a CnC machine until 1990. I’m not even sure if we can agree that PRS use was “widespread” in the 90s. The company might have grown a lot in the 90s, but I don’t remember more than a few big acts playing PRS during that time. And PRS has never had anywhere near the market share of Gibson or Fender.

Comment: I would even question the claim of "widespread adoption". They barely made a dent in EU. The 90s was a period of my life when I was at all the important trade shows & I recall no particular buzz about them in the industry. Sure, they managed to make a marketing dent in the US by grabbing some famous names on sponsorship/endorsee deals… but that's how the industry works. There were other equal or better makers at the time who didn't manage to grab the 'right' names. It was a good time to be in the 'boutique' market, so long as you had the right endorsees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRS started to become popular when Fender and Gibson were by far the dominant brands, and everyone else was either a distant wannabe, or a super-expensive product for a small niche.

In that scenario, PRS managed to carve a portion of the market for itself by combining high quality, a distinct personality, and a high, but not ridiculously so, price.

Even then, PRS never came close to challenging the domination of Gibson and Fender, something that perhaps Ibanez can claim to some extent.

In any case, answering the original question about things having to do with the quality of Gibson, no, I don't think that at all.